# Configure Renovate Bot to use custom NodeJS image

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, gitlab, renovate

I am using a self hosted Renovate Bot instance in a air gapped Gitlab to handle NodeJS module updates. I read multiple times the documentation but I do not understand how I should configure the bot to avoid the download of node and npm.

I set `dockerImagePrefix` to use the renovate image pushed in our local registry but it keeps trying to download node and npm:

```
"cmd": "/bin/sh -c docker run --rm --name=renovate_sidecar --label=renovate_child -v \"/builds/common/renovate-task/renovate/repos/gitlab/scc-2.0/app-cg\":\"/builds/common/renovate-task/renovate/repos/gitlab/scc-2.0/app-cg\" -v \"/builds/common/renovate-task/renovate/cache\":\"/builds/common/renovate-task/renovate/cache\" -e NPM_CONFIG_CACHE -e npm_config_store -e BUILDPACK_CACHE_DIR -e CONTAINERBASE_CACHE_DIR -w \"/builds/common/renovate-task/renovate/repos/gitlab/scc-2.0/app-cg\" docker.repo.asts.com/cots/renovate/sidecar bash -l -c \"install-tool node 16.14.2 && install-tool npm 8.19.4 && hash -d npm 2>/dev/null || true && npm install --package-lock-only --no-audit --ignore-scripts\"",
         
"stderr": "curl: (6) Could not resolve host: nodejs.org\ncurl: (6) Could not resolve host: nodejs.org\ncurl: (6) Could not resolve host: nodejs.org\ncurl: (6) Could not resolve host: nodejs.org\nDownload failed: https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.14.2/SHASUMS256.txt\nbash: npm: command not found\n"
```

I have a nodejs image inside the registry that I use for our production images and I would like to reuse the same in renovate process. Is it possible? And, more generally, how can I run the renovate bot with some preconfigured docker images for each programming language?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [`binarySource`](https://docs.renovatebot.com/self-hosted-configuration/#binarysource) option

Set it to `gobal` to prevent Renovate to install any tools.